# $I=\int \frac{e^{x}+\cos(x)}{e^{x}+\cos(x)+\sin(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Calculate $$I=\int \frac{e^{x}+\cos(x)}{e^{x}+\cos(x)+\sin(x)}dx$$

I tried to split the integral but I didn't get too far.$I=\int \frac{[e^{x}+\sin(x)]'}{e^{x}+\sin(x)} + ...$

Also I tried with $u=e^{x}+\sin(x)$ but I'm getting stuck.Some ideas?

Comment: not sure this integrates well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obvious facts include $$\int\frac{e^x+\cos x+\sin x}{e^x+\cos x+\sin x}dx=\int 1dx=x+C,$$$$\int\frac{e^x+\cos x-\sin x}{e^x+\cos x+\sin x}dx=\ln|e^x+\cos x+\sin x|+C.$$Averaging gives$$\int\frac{e^x+\cos x}{e^x+\cos x+\sin x}dx=\int 1dx=\frac{x}{2}+\frac12\ln|e^x+\cos x+\sin x|+C.$$

Comment: That's a great way to solve it.Thank you very much for your help:)